# If statements not catching empty lines in files

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.4

I am currently writing a static function where an open file object is passed in as a parameter. It then reads the file, and if the line is empty, it returns False. If the line is not empty, it uses the line in question plus the next three to create a new object of Person class (the class being designed in my module). For some reason, my if statement is not catching newlines, no matter what method I have tried, and I keep getting errors because of it. What am I doing wrong?

```
@staticmethod
def read_person(fobj):
    p_list = []
    for line in fobj:
        if line.isspace() or line == "\n":
            return False
        else:
            p_list.append(line)
    return Person(p_list[0],p_list[1],p_list[2],p_list[3])
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you tried doing line == "" instead? im not completely sure, but i think the read buffer uses the \n as a stop so it would not include \n

Comment: have you tried printing `repr(line)` to see what it sees? you could just do `if not line.split()`

Comment: I don't think that's your error, but I'd need to see more of the program to be sure. It's also not clear what the format of the file is (more than one record?)

Comment: Joran, when iterating a file, blank lines do come out as `"\n"`, and that string will return true `.isspace()`, so that's not the problem.

Comment: err i meant `if not line.strip()` not split ... @LeeDanielCrocker i think you meant to tell that to RNar ... (I almost said the same thing but then i wasnt sure and was too lazy to check)

Answer (score 1):

The magic you want is:

```
if line.strip() == "":
```

You can get caught up in all the little cases possible in blank line processing. Is it space-newline? space-space-newline? tab-newline? space-tab-newline? Etc.

So, don't check all those cases. Use `strip()` to remove all left and right whitespace. If you have an empty string remaining, it's a blank line, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: True, but that's not his problem.